# Cannot center large dot inside radio button

Tags: css, radio-button

I am trying to center the dot inside a radio button and it is kind of exhausting work because I cannot figure it out exactly what to do.

My final work should look something like this:

[image]

And what I've got is something like:

[image]

My code:

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #99AFC1;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 95%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 14px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
  background: #00AEEF;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color: #00AEEF;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" />
<label for="r1">Radio Button 1</label>
```

What am I missing here? I know I'm almost there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easier idea with less of code and only background coloration:

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #99AFC1;
  padding:2px; /* Control the space between border and background */
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
  border-color: #00AEEF;
  background: #00AEEF content-box; /* Don't color the padding area */
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" />
<label for="r1">Radio Button 1</label>
```

Comment: unfortunately the indicator dot goes away from the center when I zoom out my screen